# Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_DataObject_Error::whereAdd() in

Tags: php

Just wondering if someone can help with with this error. Thanks

```
    // retrieve base price
function getBasePrice()
{
    $options = DB_DataObject::factory('options');
    $options->whereAdd("name = 'price'");   // error line
    $options->find();
    $options->fetch();
    return $options->value;
}
```

Comment: Seems obvious! There is no whereAdd method

Comment: Might be useful if you are using a framework or library to tell us which one

Comment: Either the `whereAdd` method is not defined on that object, or the return value of `DB_DataObject::factory()` when this runs isn't what you think it is.